# jstree create new tree based on selected checkboxes on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to create a new checkbox tree based on the checkbox selection.
When I click submit after my selection only selected checkboxes and indeterminate parents tree should be displayed.

```
code in jsfiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chakrihacker/d2xztqok/1/

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chakrihacker/d2xztqok/1/